# How can you go fullscreen on iOS in Meteor 1.2 / Cordova 5?

Tags: cordova, meteor, meteor-cordova

I was on Cordova 3.7, and did not have the statusbar plugin. My iOS WebView extended to the top of the screen. `(0,0)` in JS was the absolute top-left of the screen, and when I set the body bg green, the whole screen is green, with black status bar text (carrier, time, battery etc) on top of the green.

I upgraded to Cordova 5.2 (Meteor 1.2), and my iOS WebView was pushed down to below the status bar. `(0,0)` in JS is now the screen's `(0,20)`, and the background of the status bar is white.

Answer (score 4):

Cordova's "fullscreen" setting is not what you want. You want to add the `cordova-plugin-statusbar`:

`meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-statusbar@1.0.1`

and do `<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />` by adding the line

`App.setPreference('StatusBarOverlaysWebView', true);`

to `mobile-config.js`.